# Ruby on Rails - Missing Attribute Error as a result of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models.

- Company
- Memorandum

I want the company to have multiple memorandums and the memorandum to have only one company.

***memorandum.rb***

```
class Memorandum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

***company.rb***

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memorandums, dependent: :destroy
  # validation lines omitted
end
```

When I try to assign the foreign key to the memorandum I get a Missing Attribute Error `can't write unknown attribute "company_id"`

I assign the company inside the companies controller. The memorandum is created prior to this and the id of the current memorandum is held inside the session hash.

***companies_controller.rb***

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)
  Memorandum.find(session[:memorandum_id]).company = @company

  respond_to do |format|
    if @company.save
      format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: does `memorandums` table has `company_id` in it  as foreign key.? please confirm

Comment: sorry pretty new to rails. I want it to how could i check?

Comment: open `rails c` in terminal. and write this `Memorandum` it will show you the attributes of the `memorandums` table

Comment: 'Memorandum(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)' - do i need a migration?

Comment: yes you need a migration in which you will do `add_column :memorandums, :company_id` this way your issue will be removed.

Comment: Thank you a ton! Sorry for such a stupid question hahaha.

Comment: a part from this `Memorandum.find(session[:memorandum_id]).company = @company` after this line you are not saving the `Memorandum` anywhere so i guess you need fetch memorandum first then set the company and save it . Welcome. no worries. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you do read the Ruby on Rails Guides for [Active Record Association.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) Concepts are very clearly explained there with example.

Here are two example links: [has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) and [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) that would help you understand.

To fix your current problem, you need a migration to add `company_id` to your `memorandums` table:

```
rails g migration addCompanyIdToMemorandums company_id:integer
```

and, then run the migration:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

As the above guide will explain, you need a foreign key in the belongs_to association's table to point it's parent table. As, your memorandums belongs_to `company`, so you have to add `company_id` in your memorandums table which we just did using the above migration.